# Вывод errorlog apache в rsyslog

Tags: linux, apache, centos, администрирование, rsyslog

Привет! Есть у меня centos6 и apache2.2 в котором много vhosts. Пытаюсь настроить сбор логов через rsyslog проставляя для каждого vhost свой tag. Выбрал **[один из методов из оф. док-ции](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlog)** через `ErrorLog syslog:user:httpd.srv1`. До каких-либо изменений лог был такой

```
Mar 13 17:09:31 srv1 httpd[20495]: [error] [client 8.8.8.8] File does not exist: /usr/share/stikked
```

После изменений, он стал такой:

```
Mar 13 17:11:54 srv1 httpd: [error] [client 8.8.8.8] File does not exist: /usr/share/stikked
```

При чём не важно, что писать в facility и tag, результат будет один и тот же: `... srv1 httpd: [error] ...`

Кусок конфига прилагаю:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/stikked
    <Directory /usr/share/stikked>
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog syslog:user:httpd.srv1
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule mod_security2.c>
        SecRuleRemoveById 106
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Собсно вопрос: А что я делаю не так? Может нужна версия apache 2.4? Или это что-то с centos? А может rsyslog как-то поднастроить надо? В общем, я не могу найти ответов :(

Comment: Так ведь в официальной документации на 2.2 нет tag-ов. Так что вряд ли такое получится.

Comment: Нда, нашёл сейчас у них там для 2.2 доки, печально всё, похоже придётся костыли городить :(

Comment: Мне даже сложно сейчас костыли представить для этого. Придется писать какие-то обертки для ошибок, с добавлением своей инфы. В документации еще сказано следующее: It is not possible to customize the error log by adding or removing information.

Comment: 2 банальных примера: 1. Читать rsyslog'ом с помощью Text File Input Module и дальше проставлять tag по имени vhost; 2. Отдавать из apache в logger; Что первый вариант, что второй, - оба полностью подчиняются аксиоме Эскобара. Других путей не вижу :(

Comment: И кстати второй вариант - очень даже вариант. ErrorLog "|/bin/logger -t vhost-1" и уже хоть что-то